# Light way to read big bz2 compressed files

Tags: linux, bash, zsh

```
bzcat *.log | sed # etc
```

works but since the files are few gb big, it takes time to complete.

Is there a way to do it in a faster way ?

I tried

```
echo *.log | xargs -P 4 bzcat | sed # etc
```

but the lines get mixed up.

Comment: I think there's no way to avoid full decompression. You already decompress to memory, so disk I/O isn't a bottleneck, at least it isn't if your file fits into memory and your machine doesn't swap. Would `bzgrep` help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make use of of multiple CPU cores (other than runnig multiple `bzip2` instances and encountering the problems you noticed) you can use a multi-threaded implementation of the bzip2 compression. There seem to be quite a few of them, unfortunately the default `bzip2` (and the `bzcat` that comes with it) is not one of them.

Here are links to a few of them, some may even come with your distribution

- [lbzip2](http://lbzip2.org/)
- [PBZIP2](http://compression.ca/pbzip2/)
- [MPIBZIP2](http://compression.ca/mpibzip2/)

For `lbzip2` there is also a `lbzcat`, but for `pbzip2`, `mpibzip` and any other implementation that tries for command line compatibility with `bzip2` the following should work:

```
pbzip2 -d -c *.log | sed # etc
```